# Running online website through virtual box/ubuntu with godaddy domain

Tags: html, linux, apache, ubuntu, virtualhost

I really need help setting my website online with my GoDaddy domain. OK this is what I've done so far, please let me know if I did anything wrong, help will be much appreciated.

Ok so what I did was:

-Download virtualbox and downloaded Ubuntu Desktop (was I supposed to download the Server one?)

-I then bought my GoDaddy domain, example.com and pointed it to my home's router/ provided my IP address.

-So then I went to my routers config and allowed port 80 to my Ubuntu Desktop's IPV4/IP address (Starts with 10.0...

-I have Apache running on my Ubuntu/Linux Desktop, and made a file in the `/etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com` and  provided the document root, server name, etc and then enabled the site using

```
sudo a2ensite example.com.
```

-I enabled bridge network on my Ubuntu and linux settings.

What else do I have to do? When I went to my router's configuration, it say's that my Ubuntu/virtual box is offline even though the Ubuntu does have internet. I'm able to access Facebook for example on my Ubuntu.

Is there anything else that I'm missing, please and please and please help. Would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Isn't there a Plesk or other kind of Control Panel?

Comment: wish your comment was informative or helpful

Comment: Well, setting up a web service within Virtual Box doesn't make almost any sense. Virtual Box installation gives you _private_ IP address (entire 10.x.x.x as well and 192.168.x.x IP ranges are reserved for private networks and are never accessible* from the outside). So in order to make a website you have to setup a "real" Linux installation with a "white" IP address (one not from private addresses ranges) and then point your DNS server to this IP address. All these operation could be rather complex for a novice, so I simply proposed a simplest solution.

Comment: * are never accessible - technically you may configure your hardware host to forward packets received in a certain port from the outside to a certain port on a private interface (that's the feature of most routers, private IP ranges are widely used to build home networks). But frankly speaking I doubt that it's what you want actually.

Comment: So I cannot run a website on my virtual host at all? The virtual box itself doesn't have a global ip address? Well thanks for letting me know that 10.0... is a private ip address. That was really helpful

Comment: I'm a beginner and don't really have a full understanding of networking. So your comment was a little informative and most of it didn't make sense haha

Comment: well, technically you can. You can assign a port (presumably 80) on your hardware host (assuming it does have a white IP address), and make all packets going to that ip.ad.re.ss:port to be forwarded to 10.0.0.x:80. See https://blogs.oracle.com/fatbloke/entry/virtualbox_vms_with_multiple_vnics to proper configure VM. And not, I won't recommend you to go this way, it's unreliable and cumbersome, especially for a novice. And actually, I didn't do a haha, I simply proposed a most convenient way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you will find this doc helpful http://catlingmindswipe.blogspot.ru/2012/06/how-to-virtualbox-networking-part-two.html But still, remember that the author of the article intends to create a sandbox, not a website for a regular use.

By the way, what is the operating system on your hardware box ?